# How to set default currency type in Libre office

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I am using **LibreOffice 5.1.4.2 10m0(Build:2)** on my Arch Linux. I would Like to set my default currency type to INR (English).

That is, Now I do this :

> Right click --> Format Cells --> Currency --> Under "format" Section, Search for INR (English) and set it (Default is USD)--> OK

I would like to have lesser steps :

> Right click --> Format Cells --> Currency  --> OK

Is there any way I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default currency can be set using the global language options. Go to Menu `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Language Settings` -> `Languages`, and select the appropriate currency from the default currency combobox:

[image]